# Using C#, can I execute a SQL query that will join two tables on separate databases with separate credentials?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlconnection

I usually create my queries locally in an environment that has several linked servers that each have there own login credentials and varying levels of permissions.  I've made the use of these queries available to collogues through simple webpages that the user can input date ranges or addresses to help narrow down the results.  Usually the page has one connection string to the database that includes the credentials.

Currently I am trying to do the same with a much more complicated query that requires me to connect to several tables on different databases that have separate log-ins.  If I were to have 2 connection strings it would be similar to the below

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=CWP;Initial Catalog=CWProd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=login1;Password=read;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
ConnectionString2 = "Data Source=GISP;Initial Catalog=GISProd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=login2;Password=read2;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
```

When I would run the query locally on Management Studio I would have no issue because I just preface each database call with the linked server name.  But I can understand why it would not be that simple for a webpage to achieve the same.  I have read access to the databases in question so I cannot create any stored procedures.  Is it possible to do this or do I need to go at this from a different angle?

The webpages do not have access to my linked servers.

Comment: Why can you not just do four part names `LinkedServer.Database.Schema.Table`

Comment: Depends on what you are using.  If EF then you would create 2 contexts and do the join using data from both.  If direct ADO access then you could again create connection using both connection strings query the each db and join results.

Comment: When you have a webpage it is a two port connection.  Port one is from client to server.  Port two is from server to database.  Normally you do not want to hard code a password into the web application.  So you need to pass the client credentials at the server to the database.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api?force_isolation=true

Comment: I quite don't understand: you say that running the query directly on the DBMS works, which means the servers themselves are correctly linked. What prevents you to make the page tell the database to run the query as is (with the linked servers referenced on it) and let the database server handle the connections?

Comment: @JoshPart they are only linked servers to my local MSSQL.  When my webpages are placed on the server that hosts them and the pages make the requests to the SQL servers they do not benefit from my local SQL bridging the connections.  Sorry for my terminology.  I am not sure how to better communicate it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting up a separate SQL server database that I have some control over on another server.  I then reproduced my linked servers on that server.  Now I can send over my query to that database and access all the linked servers I require.  Thanks for the ideas.